# not to send same file over again by FTP

Tags: python, perl, shell, ftp

I'm using following command as shell and cron it .

```
rsync -avh  --ignore-existing  ~/user/data/ root@192.168.0.104:/home/data
```

Now there is new requirement that they are deleting the file from /home/data and they want me to not send the same file once I send them and synch.

That means for every day there is folder 
**2014-12-23** and inside that, files are coming and all files are unique for that day along with the date.

**somefile_20141223_some.txt** send to them so they take it and process it and I have to have control over in locally so it will not send the same file over and over again.

So how can I achieve that with this or with normal FTP. With any of script like shell, Perl or python

Comment: Hm.. First: if you delete the file from `/home/data` how you can send it again? (it is deleted)... Don't understand your problem. Second: It is not an specific programming problem, but you're asking for an ready-to-run script what is out of scope... Please read [ask].

Comment: I send data from /user/data/ which is the source and destination is /home/data and they delete it because they process the files so I have to make sure not to send the same file again as they don't have control in their side, but currently the command that I use synch the file back in if they deleted and the result is duplicate file is processed

Answer (score 0):

When your cron calls the script frequently (every 5 minutes?) and the files you synced must remain on your local file, your script must add some householding with files have been transferred.
Which way is uo to you: grep from the rsync --log-file, or use the find -newer command.
The find is a little complex when you do not want to forget files made on the local system during the rsync/ftp:

```
function sendfile {
   echo ftp or rsync $1
}

touch ~/tmp/newsync
if [ -f ~/tmp/lastsync ]; then
   NEWERFLAG="-newer ~/tmp/lastsync"
else
   NEWERFLAG=""
fi

find ~/user/data/ ${NEWERFLAG} ! -newer ~/tmp/newsync | while read file; do
      sendfile ${file}
done
touch -r ~/tmp/newsync ~/tmp/lastsync
```

Note:
When the sync takes a lot of time, cron might try to start a second sync before the first one is finished. You should manage that (touch some lockfile and remove when finished, but think for a solution when your script crashes before deleting the lockfile).
Another method would be a 24-hour running process (sleeping a minute after processing files),
and have a cron job that checks the process running and starting it otherwise.
Ik would be nice when your process stops every day at 23:59, so logfiles can be rotated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, when I try this script it gives me error "find: unknown predicate `-older'"

Comment: Sorry, edited the solution into ! -newer (not newer).

Comment: Hi thanks, but are you sure this does send only files once even if it's deleted from destination? as in this case it keep sending the file even if I deleted them from destination, and plus this script keep running I think it's infinite loop :
sent 8.96K bytes  received 12 bytes  3.59K bytes/sec
total size is 43.76M  speedup is 4876.35
sending incremental file list
`code`
sent 8.96K bytes  received 12 bytes  2.56K bytes/sec
total size is 43.76M  speedup is 4876.35
sending incremental file list

Comment: I never used rsync myself, that's why I showed an empty function sendfile. You should fill in this function in such a way that it only sends the file given as $1.
For testing first see what the script does when you only have the echo (infinite loop here?) 
Perhaps put a sleep 1 after touch ~/tmp/newsync.

Comment: I did not tell you need to have a dir ~/tmp.
Did you really make a file ~/tmp/newsync ?

Comment: Nope I have not created any file the script itself created one for newsync and lastsync... does this append the file name physically or it keep it in memory and keep comparing it ? because when I see the file that are created are empty for both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67983/discussion-between-walter-a-and-hi4ppl).